# Is there a way to make a loop that get user input but doesn't stop if the user doesn't input anything?

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, input, syntax

Is there a way to make a loop that checks user input but doesn't stop if the user doesn't input anything?

For example:

```
while(condition){
...
selection = _getch();// the or an equivalent of getch()
...
}
```

But without the loop stopping and waiting for the user to input something.

I'm on VS if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer right after posting this, so I'll make it an answer:

Using `kbhit()` like so will solve it (at least on VS):

```
while(condition){
    if (_kbhit()) {
        char ch = _getch();
    ...
```